# Linking to region-specific Youtube search results

Tags: youtube, search, localization

Until recently, I used to be able to use different custom search engines on my browser to get Youtube results specific to a certain region. To search for results adapted for Americans, I used:

> **http://www.youtube.com/results?gl=US&hl=en&search_query**=sopa

And to search for results adapted for Brazilians, I used:

> **http://www.youtube.com/results?gl=pt-BR&hl=pt-BR&search_query**=sopa

However, now Youtube is giving me results based on my account/browser settings (or IP) no matter what URL parameter I use. Instead of changing the interface (and results) automatically, it just shows a  box with the text "View YouTube in [language in the URL parameter]".

Clicking on this would give me the results I want, but would also change my account language settings, and I would need to change them back again when I use the Brazilian search.

Is there any way to get the old functionality of changing the Youtube region/language with only URL parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I didn't find a way to do that on Youtube anymore, I've created these new generic Google video searches to get localized results:

> **http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=%s&gbv=1&ie=UTF-8&tbo=u&tbm=vid&pws=0**
>
> **http://www.google.com.br/search?hl=pt-BR&q=%s&gbv=1&ie=UTF-8&tbo=u&tbm=vid&pws=0**

Answer (score -1):

Add the `gl` parameter to target geographical areas and persist the language with `persist_hl=1`

> **http://www.youtube.com/results?gl=US&hl=en&persist_hl=1&search_query=sopa**
>   **http://www.youtube.com/results?gl=BR&hl=pt&persist_hl=1&search_query=sopa**

Comment: Can you please explain **why** this is an answer. It took me quite a while to realise that you'd added `&persist_hl=1` into the queries. So add an explanation of what this parameter is and what it does.